# java android scrollview растягивание

Tags: java, android, android-layout

У меня есть `ScrollView` и блок рекламы поверх него, который закреплен внизу экрана.

Проблема в том что блок с рекламой перекрывает последние несколько строк в `ScrollView`.

Вот визуальный пример того что происходит:

```css
.x {
position: fixed;
top: 12em;
width: 19.5em;
height: 2em;
background: brown;
}
```

```html
<h2>scrollview</h2>
<textarea cols=40 rows=10>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</textarea>

<div class="x"></div>
```

Я заметил что если тянуть данные в `ScrollView` когда скроллить больше нечего, то он немного растягивается.

Может быть есть возможность увеличить это растягивания для того чтоб контент вылез из под рекламы?

Или подскажите другое решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: `xml` покажите.

Comment: А вообще интересно, какого поведения Вы ждете, когда у Вас `есть ScrollView и блок рекламы поверх(!) него`.

Comment: post_zeew, я ничего не ждал от этого решения хорошего. Но когда блок с рекламой имеет свое выделенное место мне тоже не нравится. тогда  на телефонах с адблоком основной контент изза пустоты на том месте где должна была быть реклама, выглядит так как будто я его размер в пикселях указал и на конечном телефоне он получился меньше чем надо

Answer (score 2):

Решить Вашу проблему можно детектированием блокировщиков рекламы и, если блокировщик есть – скрывать рекламный `View`. Но есть два больших **НО**:

1. Я очень сомневаюсь, что в общем случае возможно корректно определить наличие блокировщика рекламы;
2. А стоит ли вообще это делать? Пользователь, использующий блокировщик рекламы, **априори должен быть готов к любым последствиям** работы этого самого блокировщика, так как он (блокировщик рекламы) воздействует на Ваше приложение. Это проблема или пользователя, или разработчика этого самого блокировщика рекламы, но никак не разработчика приложения. Вам не кажется абсурдным, если пользователь спросит Вас: «Слушай, чувак, я тут в твоем приложении рекламу заблокировал с помощью `%ADD_BLOCK_APP_NAME%`, но теперь у меня вместо рекламы просто белый фон, что делать?»? Пользователи, блокирующие рекламу – ССЗБ. Если же у Вас в приложении нельзя отключить рекламу, то это уже другое дело. Я считаю, что если уж и использовать рекламные баннеры, то необходимо предоставить пользователю возможность их отключения.

Comment: А что за "ССЗБ"? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Сам себе злобный Буратино, эхо фидонета.

Answer (score 0):

Всё что вам нужно - это добавить отступ внизу контента равный высоте рекламного блока.

Можно сделать через padding внутреннего контейнера или через margin для последнего элемента внутри контейнера или добавив в конец пустую вьюху или вообще поместив ScrollView выше рекламы один из множества способов так чтобы баннер не перекрывал контент

Comment: плохая идея, на телефонах с адблоком там красуется пустота. выглядит как будто кривая пиксельная верстка

Comment: @JohnDoe, юзеры с адблоком не окупают затраченное на разработку и должны страдать) А так ваша задача практически нерешаема в таком случае - только если найти способ узнать программно заблокирована ли реклама и просто ей высоту обнулить

Comment: тоесть если  я буду пользоваться своей прогой я должен страдать?)))

Comment: @JohnDoe, специально для себя сделайте админку в приложении где будет кнопка обнуления высоты баннера